# What is the keyboard shortcut for capitalization on Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2007

Also, is there an easy and comprehensive list of Word keyboard shortcuts anywhere ?

Common tasks like capitalization should not require mouse usage, and probably Word has some "hidden" or obscure shortcuts worth to know.

EDIT:
Capitalization: change a selection of text from "this" to "THIS" or "This". Just to clarify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To capitalize a word, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

This will change "this" to "This".  Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> again will change "This" to "THIS".  And once more, "THIS" back to "this".

[List of keyboard shortcuts for Word 2002, Word 2003, and Word 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290938)